# Control when a different number of requests are completed in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the following code that runs about :

```
for resFoto in resFotosResenhaEscolhidas {
        
        jsonRequestUploadImagem = ResFotosModel.createJsonFotoResenha(resFoto)
        
        let requestUploadImagem: NSMutableURLRequest = serviceRepository.clientURLRequest(wsUploadImagem, typeAutho: .basic, parms: "", body: jsonRequestUploadImagem as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
        
        serviceRepository.post(requestUploadImagem, retryLogin: true, completion: {isOk,msgError,httpCode,needLogin,response in
            self.checkResponseUploadImagemFotoResenha(response as AnyObject, httpCode)
        })
        
}

func checkResponseUploadImagemFotoResenha(_ response:AnyObject, _ httpCode:Int) {
    
    if httpCode != 200 {
        let string = String(data: response as! Data, encoding: .utf8)
        print( string!+" \n Erro HTTP: "+String(httpCode) )
        
    } else {
       // httpCode == 200
       let data: Data = response as! Data // received from a network request, for example
       let jsonResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

       print("json response upload foto")
       print(jsonResponse!)
    }
     
    
    
}
```

The serviceRepository.post just run a "urlSession.dataTask", but I wanna know how can I control when the completion of the request.

The "resFotosResenhaEscolhidas" object contains 0 to 4 array inside it depending on the call. So, the code runs and create from 0 to 4 requests.

If the 4 requests are running, I just wanna know how can I check when they are finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using a `DispatchGroup`. You'd create a `DispatchGroup` when you get ready to begin making network calls.

You'd call `enter()` on your dispatch group each time you begin a new `URLSession` task (or other async task.) You'd call `leave()` on the dispatch group in the completion handler for each task.

After you've submitted your async tasks, you'd call the dispatch group's `notify()` method to submit a block that will execute once all your async tasks are complete. (It's important that you wait until you've submitted your async tasks before calling `notify()`. If you try to call it before submitting your tasks, it invokes it's closure immediately since no tasks are running.)

I wrote a little demo project that uses a DispatchGroup to monitor a set of async tasks. (In the demo the tasks just delay for a random time before completing, and generate a random number.)

It waits until they've all completed, and then indicates the task that returned the largest value.

You can check it out on Github: [DispatchGroupDemo on github](https://github.com/DuncanMC/DispatchGroupDemo.git)